# exec.Command and terminal execution results are different

Tags: go, tfs

I want to use `tf` in my Go program. Like this:

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("tf", `workspace`, `-new`, `testsssss`, `-collection:http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs/new/`, `-login:Administrator,op@ms2019`)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

but I always get the result:

> Error: Access is denied when connecting to the TFS server
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ (authentication as an administrator)

when I run the command in terminal it works:

> tf workspace -new testsss -collection:http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs/new/
>   -login:Administrator,op@ms2019

I tried to write it to shell file, then use exec to call it, but it still failed.

Comment: Be very careful to how you pass parameters to `exec.Command`. I've spent days in trying to debug a simple command. I would not use back ticks on your variadic arguments, make an attempt at using double quotes, and if you have any spaces in your arguments, make sure to use different variadic. Also, give `bash -c` a try and quote your command.

Comment: If those are real credentials, make sure you change your administrator password immediately now that it's been posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to write it to shell file, then use exec to call it, but it still failed.

What if you try to execute that shell file manually?

You might also want to dump the HTTP traffic and figure out any notable difference. This can be done with tcpdump: `tcpdump -A -vvv port 8080`

The issue might also be related to the fact that your child process has its stdin connected to /dev/null, so if the binary is expecting to read anything there the behaviour will differ with running it from a shell manually (where the child process inherits your shell's stdin).

Comment: To check if lack of stdin is an issue you (the OP) could try running `tf …args… < /dev/null` and see if that still works.